# if statement error bash

Tags: bash

Please help me to find problem

```
t1=$(sort -k 2,2 f.txt|head -1|cut -d" " -f3)
while read x
do
t2=$(echo $x|cut -d" " -f2)
if [ $t2 -ge $t1 ] ; then
  p=$(echo $x|cut -d" " -f1)
  echo -n $p " "
fi
done <f.txt
```

**f.txt**

 F1 13 

G 13  

H 0  

 I am geeting following error

```
-sbash: [: 13: unary operator expected
-sbash: [: 13: unary operator expected
```

without H 0 row it work correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'unary operator expected' is the error when you use a binary operator with only a single operand.

This means that either t2 or t1 is empty.  To cause an empty variable to not disappear, use default notation `${VARIABLE:-DEFAULT}` to give them a default value:

```
if [ ${t2:-0} -ge ${t1:-0} ]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using bash, so use bash's internals. No need to call external cut etc. also quote your variables when you use [ ]

```
set -- $(sort -k 2,2 f.txt|head -1)
t1=$3
while read f1 f2 f3
do
t2="$f2"
if [ "$t2" -ge "$t1" ] ; then
  p=$f1
  echo -n $p " "
fi
done <f.txt
```

Comment: What? If you already have quoted the variable before the test-statement there is no need to quote it again, i even thought that was bad etiquette.

Comment: @Anders: `v1=""; [ "$v1" = '' ] && echo "match"` versus `v1=""; [ $v1 = '' ] && echo "not printed due to error"` versus `v1=""; [[ $v1 == '' ]] && echo "no quotes needed"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
t1=$(sort -k 2,2 f.txt|head -1|cut -d" " -f2)
```

instead of

```
t1=$(sort -k 2,2 f.txt|head -1|cut -d" " -f3)
```

Your `f.txt` has only two fields, so `cut` command results in nothing, and then you pass that to `[ ]`.

About why it works without the `H 0` line, I suspect that your `F` line is

```
F 1 13
```

instead of

```
F1 13
```

(This is all just a guess.)